# Rich-text field as related list column in REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I am using the format

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListB')/items?$select=FieldA,FieldB,LookupField/Field1,LookupField/Field2&$expand=LookupField
```

To join a list to a library.

The single row and date columns show up OK. but when I add the name of a Rich-text column, it complains that the column is not valid.

Doing REST get on the list itself, brings the value's HTML fine.

Had anyone success used it as related list column? if so, how?